# Hardware specification for Deep Learning research

Tags: processor, motherboard, memory, desktop, ssd

I need a Desktop computer for Deep Learning research work with large datasets. The models of Deep Learning may be huge and complex, so they may need heavy computations. My budget is INR 250000 i.e., USD 3600. To build the machine from scratch, what will be the recommended parts i.e. CPU, GPU, RAM type and size, Motherboard, HDD/SSD etc? Mentioning the producer names of the parts will be more appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of networks are you running? Do you know how large the datasets are? Are you willing to buy used?

Comment: I'm sorry to understand "sort of networks" you are asking for. The datasets may contain numeric values with 100,000 rows with about 100 features as well as text data with 10,000 files each containing a document of 100 words in average. 3D Tensors and above will also be there. I want a new machine.